# Permission Mobility in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to pass a file name to another batch file from a batch file and the second batch file gives me an "Access Denied" when I attempt to open it.

I run a function that looks similar to this:

**BATCH1.BAT**

```
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)

set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%

set DIRECTORYFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%

cd \
dir /a /s /b /o:gn > \path\%DIRECTORYFILENAME%.dr
pause
call batch2.bat
```

I know the variable is passed when an execution happens because of the next script:

**BATCH2.BAT**

```
echo with DIRECTORYFILENAME=%DIRECTORYFILENAME%
call for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (%DIRECTORYFILENAME%.dr) do (
FCIV -both "%%I" >> %DIRECTORYFILENAME%.log)
```

prints the variable but does not allow me to open the file in question with the error: Access Denied.

**EDIT**
When the other batch file is opened independantly, it will frequently hang until a Ctrl-C is pressed and then a 'N' is entered.  (If that's important)

Comment: You don't open any files.

Comment: @Mark I don't?  the call for doesn't open it automatically?

Comment: What is `do something`?

Comment: @Mark Do something is FCIV on the files listed in the PASSEDVARIABLE.ext file.  Perhaps I should have said function

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

As your question is currently, there is not enough information to reproduce your issue.

Comment: It depends on system configuration if your program can do anything. Your first two lines of bat1 are bizzare. Bat2 makes no sense either.

Comment: Hey @Mark, try this, I have added what I thought would be irrelevant code.  It might make more sense now.  Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `echo's`. Also state what is in the variables and what you want to do with them.

Comment: If, when you use `CD  \ ` if your current directory is somewhere on `C:`, you may get the "Access Denied" message because most users aren't allowed write access to the root of `%SystemDrive%` and you're trying to write your log file there. It may also be possible that you're listing directories, which you cannot access, so perhaps, `dir /a /s /b /o:gn` would be better as `Dir /B/S/A-S-L/OGN` to exclude system files & directories, and reparse points.

Comment: @Compo Brah, totally thanks, I think that more or less did it...  getting another issue but that block has now been passed!

Comment: In `BATCH2` you've missed `\path\ ` from `%DIRECTORYFILENAME%.dr`, so the loop will fail to read its content.